# Bookmark manager for local (offline) video files

Tags: windows-7, video, bookmarks, offline-files

I have a directory with several video files and subdirectories with more video files. In this case, they are photoshop tutorials, but that's not entirely relevant.

I need to bookmark several videos at several spots and keep those bookmarks all in one place, with descriptive names, so I can later come back to the sections of the videos that are relevant.

I tried VLC Player, but when saving a playlist with bookmarks, it only shows the bookmarks for the video that's playing. We do not have access to all the bookmarks for all the videos, which is what I need.

Do you have a suggestion for an app that would work?  Using Windows 7.